# What's the best way to get many items from a big table with specific IDs

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to make a query with Django to a Postgres table with millions of rows and I need to select a few hundred items with specific IDs (or another field which has an index). Right now I'm doing it like this:

```py
A_query_filter = Q(item_id=None)
    for batch_id in batch_ids:
        A_query_filter = A_query_filter | Q(item_id=batch_id)

A = Item.objects.filter(A_query_filter).order_by('-added')
```

The query is pretty slow, even though I have an index on "item_id". Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [in_bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) is what you are looking for:

```py
Item.objects.in_bulk(batch_ids, field_name='item_id')
```

Note that `in_bulk` returns a dict

UPD:
You can also query:

```py
Item.objects.filter(item_id__in=batch_ids).order_by('-added')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept the answer for now since it looks more elegant, but I'm really interested if the query is faster.

Comment: It's like 2x faster using the second method, thanks a lot